Serializing and deserializing JSON to typed objects at runtime without storing type information
Trying to create a fairly simple outbox pattern without taking dependencies on external libraries. Core thing I am trying to accomplish is handle transient failures. I use CQRS along with Mediatr to keep my view DB in eventual consistency with my transaction DB. I update view DB via in-process events via handlers. (E.g. UserCreatedEvent -> UserCreatedEventHandler)
In order to ensure events are not lost due to transient failures, I am storing them in a DB and publish them through a background process. Since handlers are typed to a class, only a single handler will execute (UserCreatedEvent is handled by UserCreatedEventHandler).
I can have X number of events types defined in a project, and they are all independent of each other in terms of properties. They will all have a common marker interface (INotification). In order to handle transient failures, when saving the transaction DB, I serialize my event and stored in DB like below.
public record SampleMessage(string Value, string Type);

//serialization
string typeOfNotification = typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName;
SampleMessage message = new(JsonSerializer.Serialize(content), typeOfNotification);

//deserialization
Type messageType = Type.GetType(message.Type)
var dvalue = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(message.Value, messageType);
await publisher.Publish(dvalue);

I have a big concern with storing type info in my objects. I might end up moving from storing these in a DB to publishing them to a broker and handle processing via an external system. I believe storing types is also no longer recommended due to vulnerabilities. What would be a good alternative to this that is maintainable?
One idea I had was storing a "Type" enum, that would just store something related to the event (e.g. UserCreated)
public record SampleMessage(string Value, MessageType Type);
public MessageType { UserCreated, UserDeleted };

//deserialize
var result = switch content.Type
{
  UserCreated=> JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserCreatedEvent>(content)
   _ => //Throw exception
 }

This is fairly straightforward but I will end up with a huge swath of switch statements and modifying this every time new events are added. Most of the answers I see related to this is using custom converters but they were mainly for polymorphic deserialization (e.g. Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net). I need to deserialize into non-polymorphic typed objects that won't have any inheritance.
What is the best practice around this?

I had a similar challenge with serializing / deserializing "book passages". Instead of "types" (Heading; subheadings; text; footnotes; etc), I included my own "simple" markup. The "Passage" (data) object "parsed" itself via "smart getters". One just "enhanced" the getters when you added new markup (to the text).

You are correct to be concerned about storing the types and using them during deserialization since that can pose a very critical vulnerability.
The dotnet's native JSON library has an interesting approach to solving this issue that I would say can be used in your situation too.
Take this example that is based on System.Text.Json versions 7+ and dotnet 8:
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Cat), "cat")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Dog), "dog")]
class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Cat : Animal;
class Dog : Animal;

The serializer uses a $type property in the generated JSON that reads as "cat" or "dog" and when deserializing the JSON, it can safely rely on the $type to map the JSON to the target type, since it's an explicitly defined discriminator name for that type and it cannot be used to maliciously load a targeted type in place of the Cat or Dog times.
By taking inspiration from System.Text.Json's approach, you will be able to implement a similar solution on your own.

You can create a custom attribute, let's say NotificationDiscriminatorAttribute that accepts a discriminator name.
You will mark your notification types with this attribute and give them a unique discriminator name.
At startup, using reflection, find all the types that are marked with this attribute and keep a dictionary of the discriminator names and their corresponding types in memory.
When serializing the messages, add an extra property like $type or $discriminator to store the discriminator name of the type extracted using reflection from the attribute.
Go ahead and use the same method that you are already using to deserialize (JsonSerializer.Deserialize(message.Value, messageType);) the message but this time use the $type or $discriminator to extract the target type from the dictionary you created at step 3 to deserialize.

Using this method, even if you use the full type name as the discriminator name (which I advise against), you are still deserializing using a predefined set of types which will prevent any malicious invocation of other types while deserializing.
Update: I got more curios and wanted to try this myself, so I wrote a simple demo.
Here you have a fully function demo:
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class NotificationDiscriminatorAttribute(string discriminator) : Attribute
{
    public string Discriminator { get; } = discriminator;
}

public class NotificationJsonConverter
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _discriminatorTypeMap;

    private readonly HashSet<Type> _notificationTypes;

    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions _options;

    public NotificationJsonConverter()
    {
        _discriminatorTypeMap = [];

        foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                NotificationDiscriminatorAttribute? attribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<NotificationDiscriminatorAttribute>();

                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    _discriminatorTypeMap.Add(attribute.Discriminator, type);
                }
            }
        }

        _notificationTypes = [.. _discriminatorTypeMap.Values.Distinct()];

        _options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,

            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        };
    }

    private bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return _notificationTypes.Contains(typeToConvert);
    }

    private bool TryGetType(string discriminator, out Type? type)
    {
        bool gotValue = _discriminatorTypeMap.TryGetValue(discriminator, out Type? t);

        type = t;

        return gotValue;
    }

    private static string GetDiscriminator(Type type)
    {
        NotificationDiscriminatorAttribute? attribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<NotificationDiscriminatorAttribute>();

        if (attribute != null)
        {
            return attribute.Discriminator;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Discriminator not found on the type.");
    }

    public object Deserialize(string json)
    {
        JsonDocument? obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonDocument>(json, _options);

        if (obj is not null && obj.RootElement.TryGetProperty("$discriminator", out JsonElement property) && TryGetType(property.GetString() ?? "", out Type? type) && type is not null && CanConvert(type))
        {
            return Deserialize(json, type);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new JsonException("Invalid Notification JSON document.");
        }
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        return (T)Deserialize(json, GetDiscriminator(typeof(T)));
    }

    public object Deserialize(string json, Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return Deserialize(json, GetDiscriminator(typeToConvert));
    }

    public object Deserialize(string json, string discriminator)
    {
        if (TryGetType(discriminator, out Type? typeToConvert) && CanConvert(typeToConvert!))
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, typeToConvert!, _options)!;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new JsonException("Type not supported.");
        }
    }

    public string Serialize(object value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();

        if (CanConvert(type))
        {
            string discriminator = GetDiscriminator(type);

            using MemoryStream memoryStream = new ();

            using Utf8JsonWriter writer = new (memoryStream);

            writer.WriteStartObject();

            writer.WriteString("$discriminator", discriminator);

            string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(value, type);

            JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(json);

            JsonElement root = document.RootElement;

            foreach (JsonProperty property in root.EnumerateObject())
            {
                property.WriteTo(writer);
            }

            writer.WriteEndObject();

            writer.Flush();

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            throw new JsonException("Discriminator not found on object.");
        }
    }

    public string Serialize<T>(T value) where T : notnull
    {
        return Serialize((object)value);
    }
}

// Step 3: Create notification types and mark them with the custom attribute
[NotificationDiscriminator(nameof(EmailNotification))]
public class EmailNotification
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

[NotificationDiscriminator(nameof(PushNotification))]
public class PushNotification
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class NonNotification
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NotificationJsonConverter converter = new ();

        string emailNotificationJson = converter.Serialize(new EmailNotification { Body = "Hello,", Subject = "World!"});
        string pushNotificationJson = converter.Serialize(new PushNotification { Message = "Hello, World!", Id = 1 });

        // Object type is EmailNotification
        object emailNotification = converter.Deserialize(emailNotificationJson);
        // Object type is PushNotification
        object pushNotification = converter.Deserialize(pushNotificationJson);


        // Note: This will fail since the class is missing the attribute
        string nonNotification = converter.Serialize(new NonNotification());

        // Note: This will fail too since the $discriminator is not a valid one set by us, hence avoiding any vulnerability
        converter.Deserialize("""{ "$discriminator": "NonNotification", "Id": 2 }""");
    }
}


Sorry for the late reply. This is a really nice concept that would auto enable adding more types down the line. As long as the event is decorated with this custom attribute it should work. I'll definitely go down this approach and see if it works out better than the enum approach I am currently using. I didn't even realize custom converters can be used to add extra properties during serialization and entirely ignore them during deserialization.

Exactly @Help123 I also came across this approach when looking into how the native JSON serializer works for polymorphic types but found the solution well suited for other scenarios too. I'm happy the solution helped you too. :)

I would indeed go for the approach you highlighted yourself, add an Enum for your message types.
However what I would recommend is tuning your analyzers to be more strict with switch expressions. A old colleague of mine wrote a nice article about it on his website: https://www.wagemakers.net/posts/exhaustive-switch-expressions
If you do this, you can get compile time errors when you accidentally forget to add an enum to your switch statements. This way your code can become more reliable.
